# Creating an Android GridView full of Buttons. Which Adapter?

Tags: android, android-gridview, simplecursoradapter, android-adapter

I need to create a GridView full of Buttons, each labelled with text from a query.

Which Adapter should I use?  A ResourceCursorAdapter, a SimpleCursorAdapater or something else?

(SimpleCursorAdpater seems like it would do the job, except I can't work out how to tell it to put the colum values as an attribute of the button, rather than the content.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the you're looking to handle the actual click event of the button (and not the actual parent grid item), I would just extend CursorAdapter and write your own custom CursorAdapter.  Inflate your own layout containing the button, set the text, and set the click event.

Comment: resourcecursoradapter takes care of the inflating for you, also

Comment: sure - resourceCursorAdapter actually implements the newView() method, which is abstract in it's parent CursorAdapter.  I just always tend to use CursorAdapter and implement newView myself.

Comment: depends - might be only 1 or 2 lines.  really not a big deal and the method is there if more needs to be added to it.